# Como percorrer adequadamente uma matriz alocada em C?

Tags: c, array, string, matriz

Sempre que percorro minha matriz de char (char**) ela altera todos as posições com o valor do ultimo nó, exemplo;

```
char** string = AlocaMatriz(10,10); //retorna uma matriz char** 10x10 allocada
    char aux[1000];
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        
        int a = (rand() % 1001);
        sprintf(aux, "%i", a);
        string[y] = aux;        
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        printf("y: %d, M: %s \n",y,string[y]);
    }
//retorno
y: 0, M: 123 
y: 1, M: 123 
y: 2, M: 123 
y: 3, M: 123 
y: 4, M: 123 
y: 5, M: 123 
y: 6, M: 123 
y: 7, M: 123 
y: 8, M: 123 
y: 9, M: 123
```

mas se eu adiciono o valor sem percorrer a matriz isso não acontece:

```
char** string = AlocaMatriz(10,1000);

string[0] ="123";
string[1] ="321";
string[9] = "332";

for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
    printf("y: %d, M: %s \n",y,string[y]);
}
 //retorno
y: 0, M: 123 
y: 1, M: 321 
y: 2, M:  
y: 3, M:  
y: 4, M:  
y: 5, M:  
y: 6, M:  
y: 7, M:  
y: 8, M:  
y: 9, M: 332
```

Preciso percorrer essa matriz adicionando valor diferente em cada uma das posições. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: sua pergunta é bem confusa, quer "percorrer" a matriz para que exatamente? se for pra mostrar o que tem não precisa mesmo alterar. Agora essa linha `string[y] = "123";` vai colcoar o mesmo valor para todos os elementos da matriz, você sabe disse certo?

Comment: Opa, vi agora o erro no exemplo. vou concertar com numeros aleatorios.

Comment: Aqui: `string[y] = aux;` você está atribuindo a`string[y]` o endereço de `aux`  portanto estará atribuindo o mesmo endereço para todos os elementos de `string`, assim no loop de impressão estará imprimindo o mesmo valor que é o último atribuído em `sprintf(aux, "%i", a);`.

Comment: Poste um programa inteiro, compilável.

Comment: O que escreveu não está assim correto. Teria que postar ALocaMatriz() para que se possa entender o que tenta fazer. Em C não existe esse conceito de matriz, como tem em FORTRAN por exemplo. Apenas vetores, eventualmente de vetores de vetores e tal. Ao declarar matriz como char** e usar uma função baseada em linha e coluna para implementar isso lembre do protótipo de main(): `int main( int argc, char** argv)` e pense porque existe `argc`e o que é um `char**`. Você deve construir como delcarou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração que você alocou espaço para string[y], substitua

```
string[y] = aux;
```

por

```
strcpy(string[y], aux);
```

Lembre de incluir `<string.h>`

`strcpy` copia uma string para outra string. Atribuindo `aux`para `string[y]` você está atribuindo apenas o endereço para a variável. Quando `aux` muda, o valor muda para todas as variáveis pois são todas um ponteiro para a mesma string.

Comment: você também pode usar o sprintf direto na string[y]: `sprintf(string[y], "%i", a);`

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo